# Updating Record Types using Execute anonymous throws INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, invalid record type: []

Tags: execute-anonymous

Looked to do something smart and immediately ran into problems. I thought I will trim the page layouts by using record types. For that I need to run a batch (or data loader), but problem I get an error mentioned in title.

Now I am not exactly sure how Execute Anonymous works but the name implies that it indeed could be related to permissions. Although I found there was a [bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1s9AAC) previously, but it is now marked as fixed.

Here's my code:

```
list <Line_del__c> linesToUpdate = [select id from Line_del__c where Team_s_Dept_s_del__r.name='BOPS'];
RecordType rtype = [Select id From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'Line_del__c' and name='office' limit 1]; 

for (Line_del__c lines: linesToUpdate){
    lines.recordtypeid=rtype.id;

}
try{
update linesToUpdate;
} catch (DmlException ex){
            system.debug(ex);
        }
```

As a side note - can I disable record types? Users now cannot edit their items from a list view. If I would update the record types I could enter them as a criteria into list view filter.

Thanks

Comment: Execute Anonymous doesn't run code 'anonymously', it runs as the currently connected user, which is you, with all of your Profile & Permission Set granted privileges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Check if the recordtype is active

2) See if the profile of the user editing the record has access to the recordtype

Go to Setup --> Administration Setup --> Profiles ( Search for the users profile ) and search for Custom Record Type Settings on the page and check if the "Office" record type is available for the users profile

Comment: Yes, the record type wasn't set active for the profiles. Couldn't figure it out until started some URL hacking. Created a second record type. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have an inactive record type named "office"?

The bug you listed was related to person accounts which does not apply to your issue given the object type.